# Decoding H264 stream with ID3D11VideoDecoder

Tags: h.264, directx-11, hardware-acceleration, dxva

I'm trying to decode (and render) H264 raw stream with DirectX11 and interface https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . Unfortunately I got stuck at sumbitting DXVA PictureParameters buffer: namely ID3D11VideoContext::SubmitDecoderBuffers always returns E_FAIL. This is very enigmatic, is there somewhere an example of using this interface to decode H264 bitstream becasue from error code E_FAIL I might never be able to conclude what I'm doing wrong? Such example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, i don't think there are some sample with ID3D11VideoContext for the h264 decoding. But there are some with IDirectXVideoDecoder (DirectX9).

**UPDATE**

The source code from MPC-**BE** is a good start. (Under src->filters->transform->MPCVideoDec).

(Ffmpeg has some use of ID3D11VideoContext, but it is not fully detailed).

**EDIT**

See my response : [How do I use Hardware accelerated video/H.264 decoding with directx 11 and windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846770/how-do-i-use-hardware-accelerated-video-h-264-decoding-with-directx-11-and-windo)