# Using DX11 and DXVA2

Tags: h.264, directx-11, hevc, dxva

I am trying to test decoding a h264/h265 video (with just a single iframe) using DX11 and DXVA2. This is on windows 7 so I probably have to interop between 2 d3d11 devices, one with 11.1 feature set and the other with 9.3. My question is since there is a severe lack of samples for loading a h264 file and decoding it using DXVA, I was wondering if there is a guide for how to layout the data to feed into DXVA to decode? I've read this [How do I use Hardware accelerated video/H.264 decoding with directx 11 and windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846770/how-do-i-use-hardware-accelerated-video-h-264-decoding-with-directx-11-and-windo) as well as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162912(v=vs.85).aspx but neither has any guide on how to do the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want a working sample to understand how to feed data into DXVA, look here : [MFNode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mfnode/). Under MFTDxva2Decoder, you will see how to feed data. It is for mpeg1/2 file format, but the same apply to H264 (with shades, of course).

**EDIT**

See my response : [How do I use Hardware accelerated video/H.264 decoding with directx 11 and windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846770/how-do-i-use-hardware-accelerated-video-h-264-decoding-with-directx-11-and-windo)

Comment: This is way overdue, but thanks for the response. Do you know if DXVA2 runs parallel to the rendering pipeline? i.e. can I have render commands on the GPU shader pipeline while at the same time using DXVA and not have them affect each other in terms of performance?

Comment: Yes, DXVA2 uses the Video Processor from GPU : it is different from shader pipeline. Those processes don't affect each other and work in parallel, but if you share texture between both, you will need some lock mechanism.