# How to use `ID311VideoContext::GetDecoderBuffer()`

Tags: c++, windows, video-processing, h.264, direct3d

I have a raw h264 stream, and would like to decode it using directx11.

I'm following [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/supporting-direct3d-11-video-decoding-in-media-foundation?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and am the section to actually start decoding frames. (ie Calling BeginDecodeFrame())

I'm also following some advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846770/how-do-i-use-hardware-accelerated-video-h-264-decoding-with-directx-11-and-windo):

Which references an older verson of the same docs I linked previously. Anyway, it's saying that I need to fill some buffers:

```
D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_BUFFER_PICTURE_PARAMETERS
D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_BUFFER_INVERSE_QUANTIZATION_MATRIX
D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_BUFFER_BITSTREAM
D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_BUFFER_SLICE_CONTROL
```

I'm relatively familiar with h264, and understand I can get this information from parsing the NALU's. That being said, I don't want to manually parse the h264 packets themselves, It seems like there should be some kind of convenience method to do this for me.. **So is there??**

Coming from the Mac world, I can just call: `CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets` with the PPS and SPS data and that'll handle it for me.

A follow up on that, how exactly do I "Fill These Buffers" ?

```
HRESULT GetDecoderBuffer(
  [in]  ID3D11VideoDecoder              *pDecoder,
  [in]  D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_BUFFER_TYPE Type,
  [out] UINT                            *pBufferSize,
  [out] void                            **ppBuffer
);
```

The function signature expects an out param of (void**), so if I wanted to fill `D3D11_VIDEO_DECODER_BUFFER_PICTURE_PARAMETERS`, how do exactly to do I fill it with the parsed data? Do I need to assign a pointer to `DXVA_PictureParameters` and then cast it as a void** like: `(void**)&myPictureParamets` when I call the function?

The linked docs state:

> Direct3D 11 uses the same data structures as DXVA 2.0 for decoding operations.

So I'm kind of guessing on `DXVA_PictureParameters` being the correct struct to use here.

I was expecting this to be easier than it has been! :P